# jquery get image of display block

Tags: jquery

I have following code

```
<div class="img">
<img src="image/1.jpg" class="img_s" style="display:none;" />
<img src="image/2.jpg" class="img_s" style="display:none;" />
<img src="image/3.jpg" class="img_s" style="display:none;" />
<img src="image/4.jpg" class="img_s" style="display:block;" />
<img src="image/5.jpg" class="img_s" style="display:none;" />
<img src="image/6.jpg" class="img_s" style="display:none;" />
</div>
```

How can i get the image src with the style of display block?

Thank you so much for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `:visible pseudo selector` should do it:

```
 var imagesrc = $('.img').children('img:visible').attr('src');
```

Ref.: [:visible selector](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/)

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".img_s[style='display: block;']");
```

Comment: @cicakman - I think the solution by jAndy is better - please accept his